# Advise on changing from SQL Server to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have written an application: parser and web portal. They are both using SQL Server.

The customer requires it to be in mySQL.

Do you know are they equivalent for SQL scripts?

I think I need to install Connector/NET (http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) for doing so. Right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: About the .NET provider for MySQL - have a look at this dotConnect provider - http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**: Are MSSQL and MySQL equivalent?
**Answer**: NO. There are quite a few differences

See http://www.x7media.com/resources/SQL_Differences_Between_Microsoft_SQL_Server_and_MySQL.asp for the differences in syntax.

**2**: MySQL connector:
**Answer**: Yes. To use any database system, you need to install its connector. The MySQL connector is available at the url you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**First answer:** no, MySQL and MS-SQL are not equivalent for sql scripts if you use specific functions (for example `LIMIT` for MySql and `TOP` for MS-SQL). So if you want every single query execute without problems you have to use standard SQL clauses.
To make it better you could convert database logic with the use of [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) (if you use [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) it will be even easier) so you can describe and manage your database using classes, while database part is managed internally, so your code become portable with the most known databases withouth changing a single line of your code.

**Second answer:** if you want to use MySQL, you must use [MySQL Connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).